# Log question using TI-83 - total newb

Tags: logarithms

I am trying to figure out how to solve a math problem and am awful at math so go easy on me. We are working on logarithms. I am given the answer though I'd like to know how to solve it on my calculator.

$\log 1.8 = \log 1.0205{^2t}$

$\log 1.8 = 2t * \log 1.0205$

$t = \frac{\log 1.8}{2 \log 1.0205}$

$t = 14.4827$

somehow they figured this out on the calculator and I can't figure out how.

Every time I type in $\log 1.8$ on the calculator I get $.2555$.

If anyone can help a total math dummy figure out how to use a TI-83 plus to figure this out I'd be very grateful. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Is it $2t$ or $t^2$?  You use $2t$ and $t2$ in your post.  Have you searched for a TI-83 Plus manual?  They seem to be available

Comment: It is 2t, that is the exponent. I am trying to edit.  So sorry.

Comment: You are using base $10$ logs, and $\log_{10}1.8 \approx 0.2555$.  Do you understand this?

Comment: Nope! I sure don't.

Comment: Yes I have watched videos and looked at a manual, that is not my issue. My issue is understanding the math.  @RossMillikan

Comment: In mathematics the $\log$ is the natural logarithm by default, on calculators it often defaults to the $\log_{10}$ and the natural logarithm is obtained with the $\text{ln}$ key. In your case, both versions of the log should give the same result because you are dividing two logs.

Comment: Note that in other sciences such as seismology or astronomy, the notation $\log$ often defaults to $\log_{10}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two types of logarithms on a calculator - the common logarithm in base $10$, denoted by $\log x$, and the natural logarithm in base $e = 2.7182818...$, denoted by $\ln x.$  Sometimes, $\log x$ will often represent $\ln x$ while the base ten logarithm will be noted as $\log_{10} x$.

When you hit the $\log$ button on your TI-83, the calculator computed your equation using the common logarithm.  That is, $$t = \dfrac {\log 1.8}{2 \log 1.0205} = \dfrac {0.2553}{0.0176} = 14.4827.$$

When you hit the $\ln$ key, you're computing using natural logarithms, so you get $$t = \dfrac {\ln 1.8}{2 \ln 1.0205} = \dfrac {0.5878}{0.0406} = 14.4827.$$

Note that the answers for each are equal.

CAVEAT: In order to get similar results, you must use the same base. Using two different bases will produce different results, that is $$t = \dfrac {\ln 1.8}{2 \log_{10} 1.0205} = \dfrac {0.5878}{0.0176} = 33.3477.$$ while $$t = \dfrac {\log_{10} 1.8}{2 \ln 1.0205} = \dfrac {0.2553}{0.0406} = 6.2898.$$